# Operator overload of class wrapped in smart pointers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, c++14

I've been trying to make some operator overloads (* and +) on a class which is wrapped in smart pointers.

```
auto p = std::make_unique<Polynomial<T>>();
```

When I try to overload it using normal overloading, it obviously asks for the smart pointer types.

Edit, so:

```
std::unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>> operator+(const std::unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>>& right);

template<class T>std::unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>> Polynomial<T>::operator+(const std::unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>>& right) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

And the error:

[image: Error from trying to use the + operator]

So how do you go about overloading the normal operators when the class is encapsulated in a smartpointer?

Comment: "When I try to overload it using normal overloading, it obviously asks for the smart pointer types." -- What.

Comment: Why are these classes wrapped in smart pointers? Why can't you use them as value types?

Answer (score 11):

**Don't.**

Run those operations on the pointees, not on the pointers:

```
*p = *p + *p
```

It would be very confusing for users of your code if suddenly pointers had completely different and unexpected semantics.

It would be confusing for you, too.

Answer (score 3):

For a direct answer to your question, I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit: **Just don't**. But the reason to write another answer is that the question you are asking sounds a bit like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

You have a class `Polynomial<T>` but you expect the user to wrap it in a smart pointer? This is fishy as a sane design would just expect the user to work with `Polynomial` directly, hence providing normal operators that work on that type directly.

Take a step back and think about why you think a smart pointer would be used/needed/helpful. Often, this is done for presumed efficiency reasons, right? But that just means you should rethink how you implemented `Polynomial` itself. Look into the following:

- Does `Polynomial` have move-constructor and -assignment? If not, implement it.
- What about the stored data? Maybe the internal storage should be managed by a smart pointer. Together with move-semantics, this can lead to very efficient operations.
- For operator overloading, implement `a+=b;`, use a library to have `a+b` generated for you. Check [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/operators.htm) or my [df.operators](https://github.com/d-frey/operators/), the latter is also move-aware.

With the right implementation, the urge to use `std::unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>>` should go away :)

Comment: `template<class Lhs, class Rhs> friend Polynomial operator+( Lhs&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs ) { Polynomial ret = std::forward<Lhs>(lhs); ret += std::forward<Rhs>(rhs); return ret; }` -- why do you need a library for that?  I guess you could presume commutativity, and conditionally use left or right in that case for the initial `ret`?  And SFINAE tests, I presume.  And some work to avoid conflicting `operator+` ambiguity.

Comment: @Yakk Some people disagree with my approach, but with overloads for temporaries, you can optimize further by returning an rvalue-reference instead of a new object in some cases. "Move-aware" means more to me than your implementation. Especially for classes where additional temporaries have a significant cost and `Polynomial<T>` looks exactly like one of those cases.

Comment: Never, ever return an rvalue reference (outside of cast expressions): it means reference lifetime extension fails to work.  Something as simple as `for( coeff x : a+b )` won't work!  And what good is that!

Comment: @Yakk As I said, some people disagree. Now please go ahead and tell all the people writing "adapters" like `for( auto i : some_cool_reverse_adapter(get_my_container()))`. For some reason everyone accepts that they do it, only I get called out for it. As far as I'm concerned, range-based for-loop is broken as it should extend the lifetime of all temporaries of the expression, as any function call would do. Temporary solution: Don't use range-based for loops with expressions like the `a+b` or `f(g())` or anything "dangerous". Anyways, I don't want to have that discussion again.

Comment: @DanielFrey Returning rvalue references is, *generally* speaking, nonsensical. It also prevents copy elision.

Answer (score 2):

> So how do you go about overloading the normal operators when the class is encapsulated in a smartpointer?

Just declare them as you would normally:

```
template<typename T>
Polynomial<T> operator*(Polynomial<T> lhs, Polynomial<T> rhs) { ... }

template<typename T>
Polynomial<T> operator+(Polynomial<T> lhs, Polynomial<T> rhs) { ... }
```

and then given something like:

```
auto p = std::make_unique<Polynomial<int>>();
auto q = std::make_unique<Polynomial<int>>();
```

just call:

```
auto x = (*p) * (*q);
auto y = (*q) + (*p);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b74c54d0142df2fa)

---

The error you provided:

[image]

is due to the fact that your operator overloading:

```
std::unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>> operator+(const std::unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>>& right);
```

is overloading the *unary* `operator+` for expressions like `+x`.

And the other:

```
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>> Polynomial<T>::operator+(const std::unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>>& right) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

is overloading `operator+` for operands of type `Polynomial<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>>`.

Therefore given two `unique_ptr<Polynomial<T>>`, namely `x` and `y`, the following expression:

```
x + y
```

does not find an overload resolution for `operator+`.

I also highly discourage the overloading of operators for standard library types.